# Using WordPress login system for an entire website?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wordpress-login

My website runs WordPress, but I have plenty of static pages as well. I'm looking to integrate a user login system, and rather than reinventing the wheel, I was going to open my WordPress login system to the public (default new users to Subscriber).

Are there any major risks to this? Is it not recommended?

EDIT: Found this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/soap-authentication/) in another thread. Would something like this be required?

Comment: Asking for opinions or recommendations is off-topic, see [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known drawback with using WP's login system, it's WP after all, you can allow people to log in/out from the frontend using [Sidebar Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-login/)

Yet, the only drawback I see with this is that it will be so obvious that you are using WordPress and you won't be able to customize the look and feel of the backend as if you were using Drupal (where you can set backend themes).

Other than that, you will probably want to:

- Modify roles: [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)
- Remove some admin pages and menus : [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)
- Remove unused profile fields : [Remove Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-fields/)